# JQuery mobile v1.2 javascript event not working in pop-up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a web app with JQuery Mobile 1.2 and php. From the profile page, I have a popup asking the user to confirm logout. What I want to do is intercept that button with a click event to process the logout via an ajax request.

I have a custom.js file included in all my project pages. The app loads in the accounts page. I know it is getting loaded and working across the ajax navigation.
When I include this code in custom.js:

```
$("#perfil").live('pageshow',function(event){
    alert('This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!'); 
});
```

I get the alert when the profile page is shown. The problem is the click function.

When I include this:

```
$("#perfil").live('pageshow',function(event){
    alert('This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!'); 

    $('#logoutButton').click(function(){
        $('#output').html('Logging Out...');
        $.get("api/logout",function(data){
            if(data.success) {
                window.location = "index"
            }
            else{
                $('#output').html('Logout failed. Try again');
            }
            }, "json");
    });

});
```

The behavior is odd. When I navigate from the main page to the profile page, I get the alert. But the button doesn't respond. However, when I refresh (or initially load the app from the profile page) the button behaves correctly and runs the the javascript logout function.

Here is the code for the html button:

```
<a id="logoutButton" data-role="button" data-icon="check" 
      data-inline="true" data-theme="e">Si, finalizar.</a>
```

Comment: I apologize for the formatting... Cant seem to get it to read correctly.

Comment: For future reference the *back-tics* are meant for formatting code inline, for formatting blocks of code you indent it by four spaces, or you can use the toolbar by highlighting your code and clicking the *format code* button *{}*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom.js on your *profile page* is not actaully getting loaded (more on that below), and as a result when you are binding the click event your button does not exist in the DOM, you can get around this by using event delegation for example

```
$(document).on('click', '#logoutButton', function(){
        $('#output').html('Logging Out...');
        $.get("api/logout",function(data){
            if(data.success) {
                window.location = "index"
            }
            else{
                $('#output').html('Logout failed. Try again');
            }
            }, "json");
    });
```

Now the reason why your custom.js isn't getting loaded is because by default when you load a page in jQuery Mobile the [default behavior](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html) is to load just the `data-role="page"` div via ajax and attach it to the DOM of the current page. The important part to realize is that only the *div page* gets loaded, and **not** any other resources on that page.

If you want a custom script on a seperate page to be loaded you need to include it within the div `data-role="page"` wrapper. You can also tell JQM to fully load a page without ajax by using the `data-ajax="false"` attribute on your links (or `rel="external"` if its a different domain).

As a side point you should consider using [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.live` as of jQuery 1.7 `.live` has been [depreciated](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: Wow. Works great. Thanks a ton for your help. Was causing me massive headaches...

Answer (score 0):

In JQM, it all depends on how your data is initialized and how the pages are structured.

When loading your main page, all scripts are initialized once and cached for "Ajax" like response and feel.

If your main and profile page are in a multi-page format, your click button won't be an issue as the scripts are initialized once.

Or if you are in a single page, rel="external" from main to profile page will work. External links will force JQM to make a new HTTP request; However, you do loose page transition effects.

I believe a better architecture is to create single JQM pages and utilize a log-out button
Log-out as a binding function.

*How to bind your click function:

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});
```

[Source](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/experiments/api-viewer/docs/bind/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yeah, my pages are in multi-pages. I have a different file for each page. The script is initialized but for some reason it doesn't intercept the click... The alert however works which  tells me it is getting called...